# MySite Branding Event Receiver not firing

Tags: branding, mysite, feature-stapling

I followed [this](http://sharepointologic.blogspot.in/2013/04/branding-sharepoint-2013-my-sites-with.html) blog for creating mysite branding for sharpoint 2013.Everything works fine but  feature stapler doesnt work for new Personal sites. but if i manually activate the feature than it works fine. also through powershell if i specify correct feature id , branding gets applied. but i want this to happen automatically. please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced the same issue. Please make sure that the feature id that you have mentioned in feature stapler must be exactly same as feature id by which you are deploying your event receiver.

Please check the below post "http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/apply-custom-theme-to-sharepoint-2013-mysite-using-feature-stapling"

**Point to be noticed in the above post**: Be noted that you need to use the Guid of the “MySiteThemeFeature”. To get the Guid for the feature, see its manifest. The below is the manifest for MySiteThemeFeature.

This might help you. :)

Comment: thanks. i solved that long back almost one and half year back!. Even after using correct guid for features, you still need to re-do the event receiver again if you have deployed event receiver before with incorrect GUID!

Answer (score 0):

try attaching OWSTimer and debug. If you find weird behavior ( null exception on SPSite)  just restart the timer service. - by this time this issue must have resolved itself.
However, if there's any errors underlying in the logic it will come out on debugging.